# iterate over lines in file and expand global variables

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script which will iterate over the lines in a file and expland the global variables at the same time.

I have a global variable `$SOURCE_CODE_DIR` defined in my bashrc file.  Lets say that 
`$SOURCE_CODE_DIR` == /path/to/source/

My external file looks like this:

```
$SOURCE_CODE_DIR/some/dir/file.txt
$SOURCE_CODE_DIR/some/dir/file.cpp
```

and my bash script so far is:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read line
do
  echo $line
done < /path/to/external/file/above.txt
```

the variable $SOURCE_CODE_DIR is being used in other places in the script, so is accessible and defined correctly;

The output of this script is

```
$SOURCE_CODE_DIR/some/dir/file.txt
$SOURCE_CODE_DIR/some/dir/file.cpp
```

and not

```
/path/to/source/some/dir/file.txt
/path/to/source/some/dir/file.cpp
```

Can anyone help me expand the $SOURCE_CODE_DIR variable so I can use it?

Comment: You need to use double quotes `echo "$line"`

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `eval`:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read line
do
  eval echo $line
done < /path/to/external/file/above.txt
```

Comment: I know your comment was correct also - but @Antarus the points more than you.  But thank you, never-the-less.

Comment: @Martyn Oh, it's ok.  (BTW, just observe the time for the two answers!)

Comment: ahh...you're so right - you were first - I misread the times.  corrected - first always wins in my books

Comment: Ah! you help bring Firefox to our devices!

Comment: Yeah - I'm currently working on Android web runtime - helping bring web apps to Android which look and feel native :)

Comment: well just noticed 2 answers were similar. Deleting Mine.